# How to not run the rest of an If statement if one is false?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, nested

For the following program, if an answer to any question makes the user ineligible to vote then how do I make the program say so right away and not ask the remaining questions?

```
def main():
    print("This program determines if a user is eligible to vote in the US\n")

    q1 = str(input("Are you a US citizen? y/n: "))
    q2 = int(input("What is your age?: "))
    q3 = str(input("Do you meet your state's residency requirement? y/n: "))

    if q1 == "n":
        print("\nNot eligible to vote.")
    elif q2 < 18:
        print("\nNot eligible to vote.")
    elif q3 == "n":
        print("\nNot eligible to vote.")
    else:
        q1 == "y"
        q2 >= 18
        q3 == "y"
        print("\nYou are eligible to vote!")
main()
```

Comment: Ask question 1, check if it is valid, `return` if not. Then ask question 2, rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a nested "if else" statement, exiting when one of the questions is wrong . Like so:

```
def main():
print("This program determines if a user is eligible to vote in the US\n")

q1 = str(input("Are you a US citizen? y/n: "))
if q1 == 'y':
    q2 = int(input('What is your age?:  '))
    if q2 > 18:
        q3 = str(input('Do you meet your states residency requirement? y/n:  '))
        if q3 == 'y':
            print("\nYou are eligible to vote!")
        else:
            print("\nNot eligible to vote.")
            exit()
    else:
        print("\nNot eligible to vote.")
        exit()
else:
    print("\nNot eligible to vote.")
    exit()
main()
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: Um... that wasn't really the point. I was just demonstrating the code that fizzy would need.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need the results from the questions again later, you can just put the `input` into the `if` condition and chain them with `and`. This way, the second `input` is not asked again if the first one already decided the outcome of the condition, and same for the third.

```
if (input("Are you a US citizen? y/n: ") == "y" and
        int(input("What is your age?: ")) >= 18 and
        input("Do you meet your state's residency requirement? y/n: ") == "y"):
    print("\nYou are eligible to vote!")
else:
    print("\nNot eligible to vote.")
```

You could also combine that with `(...)` or `or` to get more complex conditions, although at some point using a nested `if/else` structure might become more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check the input of the user after every `input` statement. You can use an if-else statement each time. In case the answer is wrong, print something and then use `return` and the remaining code in the `main()` function will not be executed. The remaining questions will not be asked.